# Why MikTeX on Win10?

Tags: miktex

I see that there is a LaTeX package available for Windows.  I was recommended to install MikTeX on my PC w/ Windows10.

Why would one choose one over the other?

Comment: What do you mean by "a latex package"?

Comment: note that you need a tex system to run latex, the two main ones are miktex and texlive, which you choose is really just a matter of taste, the latex functionality is the same in either case.

Comment: "LaTeX package", as in a software package available on a website to download to my home computer.